# How to make jQuery tabs that update active or selected tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want jQuery tabs but I want it to change the one that's selected via the .selected CSS property, how can I do that with jQuery tabs?  I tried addClass and removeClass to no avail.

Thanks very much.

Code below:

```
<div class='content'>
   <div class='tabs'>
        <div id='resultsTableNav'>
            <a href='#tab-1' class='resultsButton selected'>MY BETS</a>
            <a href='#tab-2' class='resultsButton'>ALL BETS</a>
            <a href='#tab-3' class='resultsButton'>ON CHAIN</a>
            <a href='#tab-4' class='resultsButton'>CHAT</a>
            <a href='#tab-5' class='resultsButton noMargin'>FAIR</a>
        </div><!-- end resultsTableNav -->

<div id='tab-1'>
        <table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' class='resultsTable'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>NAME</td>
                    <td>BET ADDRESS</td>
                    <td>WIN ODDS</td>
                    <td>PRIZE MULTIPLIER</td>
                    <td>HOUSE PERCENT</td>
                    <td>MIN BET</td>
                    <td>MAX BETS</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                for($i=0; $i<=12; $i++)
                {
                    if($i%2==0)
                        $class='greyRow';
                    else
                        $class='';
                    ?>
                    <tr class='<?php echo $class; ?>'>
                        <td>Developer</td>
                        <td><div class='addressScroll'>1ChqhkyQENiuG4J6UDCvNjfiLJp5zkqhX7</div></td>
                        <td>97.6563%</td>
                        <td>1.004x</td>
                        <td>1.900%</td>
                        <td>0.0100</td>
                        <td>500.0000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
  </div>
</div>
 </div><!-- end content -->
```

Comment: As it is like now, I find it somewhat difficult to grasp what you're trying to do. Would you be able to update your question by adding some of your jQuery code, if possible?

Comment: $('.tabs').tabs();  isn't working.